# Maintain votes cast after daily limit and automatically validate them the next day

Tags: feature-request, voting, voting-limits

I have voted 40 votes to the frequently asked questions, so there are no more votes for me for the rest of the day. It will be good to limit the user's votes, but when the user cast the further votes they should be saved and should be added to the respective question or answer when he got some votes in the later day. Because we may not remember to vote the people after the completion of the day.

Today I have cast 40 votes. After some time one person responded to my question with a good answer. There is no possibility for me to vote on it, because my votes for the day are over. I may not remember to vote tomorrow. Who knows, I may not visit Stack Overflow tomorrow. But his answer needs to get appreciation.

For this reason I would suggest to keep track of the votes cast beyond the daily limit, and to automatically validate them once I could vote again.

Comment: You are not supposed to cast all votes to a single person's question/answer. A single vote (and accept if it is your question) is enough.

Comment: Pragnani, try to make your point in concise, compact sentences. Avoid redundancy. It **will** be [harder and take longer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TimeToMakeItShort), but it will also make people more likely to read it, understand it and respond. (Also, I re-wrote this comment 2 times before posting ;-))

Comment: And when you exceed your next day's limit as well, then what ? Save the votes for the day after tomorrow ?

Comment: AshRj, it can be really scalable. Just keep a list of to-be-voted-on content and pop some of them each day. Makes it possible to put in a century of votes in advance!

Comment: Thanks for edit @gnat.. I was not that much good in my language...

Comment: Yeah @gnat, thanks. ;)

Comment: May I also warn you: please do not target votes exclusively at certain users, or have friends or coworkers vote only for your questions or answers. Votes must come based on the merit of the individual posts, not because of who is leaving them.

Comment: @Bart thanks for letting me hijack [your contribution](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/164625/revisions "in rev 2") :)

Comment: @BradLarson sure defanately.....I was just go through the questions in faq's and I was pretty much impressed by answers so I have voted all my votes. but at the same time some user responded to my questions but I don't have any more votes for the rest of the day, so I have thought of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you see an answer that needs appreciation, but you don't have any votes left for today, make a note to revisit that post tomorrow;

- You can star the message and it will appear in your favorites
- or you can simply create a bookmark in your browser.
- Another option would be to leave a comment expressing your appreciation and explaining the conundrum you find yourself in (no votes left for today). Your comment history is saved in your [activity tab on your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727092/pragnani?tab=activity&sort=comments). Using this method allows you to keep track of comments you've made (which will then allow you to return to that post) and also provides some immediate verbal appreciation for the poster which should suffice until the UTC clock ticks over midnight and you get another 40 votes to distribute.

I don't think that the system should "save" votes and then execute them once the user's vote limit has been reset...

This would totally negate the point of a daily limit.